# move SVG group on path trail based on percentage of whole path trail

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I am trying to find a way to move an group (id="avatar") inside an SVG with jQuery based on an percentage of the whole trail of an path element (id="path" > path), inside the SVG.

So set the avatar with transform->translate to the right position dynamically for example 20% of the trail. So te input is 20, then it should be set on 20% of the trail of #path > path.

I can't find any sort of function or parsing mechanism to archive this goal.

Any suggestions?

The SVG is used in the browser as an whole SVG html5 element with all their nested SVG tags. So not loade like in an img->src.

SVG image:
[image: the svg]

SVG code:

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 1000 600" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st5{fill:#43A592;stroke:#8C6239;stroke-width:0.5;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st6{fill:none;stroke:#603813;stroke-width:8;stroke-linecap:square;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st7{fill:none;stroke:#603813;stroke-width:8;stroke-linecap:square;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-dasharray:5.0414,12.0993;}
    .st8{fill:#405813;}
    .st9{fill:#7FBFD6;}
</style>
<g id="path">
    <path class="st7" d="M253.83,291.92C438.6,278.28,338.5,457,422.2,429.99c87.72-28.31-71.17-110.68,22.64-190.57
        c54.07-46.05,161.79-22.03,138.18,79.89c-13.69,59.11-53.79,87.21-30.99,132.4c0,0,20.26,23.49,61.35,18.96"/>
</g>
<g id="avatar" transform="translate(10,20)">
    <g>
        <g>
            <circle class="st9" cx="276.22" cy="290.06" r="26.83"/>
            <path class="st8" d="M276.22,317.69c-15.23,0-27.62-12.39-27.62-27.62s12.39-27.62,27.62-27.62s27.62,12.39,27.62,27.62
                S291.45,317.69,276.22,317.69z M276.22,264.04c-14.35,0-26.03,11.68-26.03,26.03s11.68,26.03,26.03,26.03
                s26.03-11.68,26.03-26.03S290.57,264.04,276.22,264.04z"/>
        </g>
        <g>
            <g>
                <path class="st16" d="M264.95,293.51c-0.35-0.11-0.74,0.03-0.93,0.35l-4.62,7.56c-0.35,0.58,0.02,1.33,0.7,1.39
                    c3.16,0.29,11.31,1.43,23.76,5.78c0.44,0.15,0.86-0.3,0.65-0.73C283.15,305.1,278.44,297.84,264.95,293.51z"/>
            </g>
            <g>
                <path class="st16" d="M284.68,279.17c-2.01-6.83-8.8-10.85-15.17-8.97c-0.04,0.01-0.09,0.03-0.13,0.04
                    c-0.06-0.01-0.13-0.01-0.19-0.02c-0.07,0.05-0.13,0.09-0.19,0.14c-6.04,2.09-9.34,8.94-7.39,15.59c0,0-0.76,2.95-2.22,5.82
                    c0,0,6.79-0.4,8.31-7.6c0,0,0.02,0.05,0,0l9.33-2.75c0.01,0.03,0,0,0,0c8.13,6.32,13.75,1.44,13.75,1.44
                    S287.35,280.89,284.68,279.17z"/>
            </g>
            <g>
                <path class="st8" d="M296.91,298.57c-0.04-0.3-0.29-0.52-0.59-0.52h-3.56c-0.33,0-0.6,0.27-0.6,0.6c0,1.34-0.33,1.94-0.6,2.2
                    c-0.18,0.18-0.4,0.27-0.65,0.26c-0.47-0.01-1.14-0.76-1.62-1.83c-1.25-2.77-3.05-3.78-4.49-4.12v-1.83
                    c0-0.07,0.06-0.12,0.12-0.12h1.72c0.09,0,0.19-0.02,0.27-0.06c0.25-0.12,0.37-0.39,0.33-0.64c-0.46-2.69-1.3-5.53-1.85-7.27
                    c3.56-0.05,5.75-1.89,5.78-1.92c0.15-0.13,0.22-0.32,0.2-0.51c-0.02-0.19-0.13-0.36-0.3-0.46c-0.03-0.02-3.07-1.76-5.62-3.38
                    c-0.17-0.11-0.31-0.28-0.37-0.47c-2.19-6.54-8.67-10.46-14.95-9.07l0.35-0.89c0.12-0.31-0.04-0.67-0.36-0.78
                    c-0.31-0.11-0.65,0.07-0.77,0.37l-0.34,0.87c-0.05,0.14-0.23,0.19-0.35,0.1l-0.69-0.52c-0.27-0.2-0.65-0.14-0.85,0.13
                    c-0.19,0.27-0.11,0.64,0.15,0.84l0.74,0.55c-5.7,2.43-8.79,9.05-7.12,15.55c0.05,0.2,0.04,0.4-0.03,0.59
                    c-0.34,0.99-1.18,3.34-2.03,5.27c-0.07,0.15-0.08,0.32-0.02,0.47c0.09,0.24,0.32,0.38,0.56,0.38c0.01,0,0.03,0,0.04,0
                    c0.04,0,2.17-0.17,4.39-1.48c0.22,0.56,0.48,1.26,0.69,2.01c-0.4,0.06-0.78,0.29-1,0.66c0,0,0,0,0,0l-4.62,7.56
                    c-0.28,0.45-0.3,1-0.06,1.47c0.24,0.47,0.69,0.78,1.21,0.83c2.93,0.27,11.11,1.37,23.62,5.75c0.12,0.04,0.25,0.06,0.37,0.06
                    c0.32,0,0.62-0.13,0.84-0.38c0.3-0.34,0.37-0.83,0.17-1.24c-0.72-1.48-2.29-4.05-5.38-6.8c0.84,0.21,1.68,0.35,2.49,0.42
                    c0.07,0.01,0.14,0.01,0.2,0.01c0.64,0,1.26-0.23,1.72-0.66c0.47-0.43,0.72-1.02,0.72-1.67v-2.29c2.23,0.86,2.77,2.18,3.39,3.7
                    c0.38,0.93,0.76,1.89,1.54,2.82c0.8,0.96,1.75,1.43,2.91,1.43c0.27,0,0.56-0.03,0.85-0.08
                    C296.75,303.92,297.15,300.37,296.91,298.57z M285.22,280.22c1.65,1.04,3.43,2.09,4.44,2.68c-1.61,0.93-5.77,2.54-11.3-1.25
                    l5.51-1.62C284.32,279.9,284.81,279.97,285.22,280.22z M272.69,270.34c4.78,0,9.32,3.21,11.14,8.16
                    c0.05,0.15-0.03,0.3-0.18,0.35l-5.99,1.76c-0.1,0.03-0.21-0.03-0.24-0.14c-0.25-1-0.74-2.77-1.58-4.6
                    c-1.2-2.63-2.68-4.48-4.37-5.47C271.89,270.36,272.29,270.34,272.69,270.34z M269.12,271.08c0.15-0.15,0.37-0.21,0.57-0.15
                    c4.12,1.11,6.06,7.7,6.59,9.9c0.02,0.1-0.03,0.2-0.13,0.23l-7.73,2.27c-0.1,0.03-0.2-0.02-0.23-0.12
                    C267.48,281.06,265.68,274.45,269.12,271.08z M266.97,272c-0.94,1.77-1.27,4.06-0.98,6.79c0.22,2.01,0.72,3.77,1.04,4.74
                    c0.03,0.1-0.02,0.21-0.13,0.24l-4.61,1.35c-0.15,0.04-0.3-0.05-0.34-0.2C260.81,279.76,262.91,274.58,266.97,272z
                     M261.95,286.82c0.08-0.24,0.28-0.42,0.52-0.49l4.57-1.34c-1.35,4.32-4.91,5.64-6.67,6.03
                    C261.03,289.4,261.63,287.72,261.95,286.82z M283.89,307.97c-12.54-4.37-20.77-5.48-23.74-5.75c-0.16-0.01-0.23-0.13-0.25-0.17
                    c-0.02-0.05-0.07-0.18,0.01-0.31c0,0,4.62-7.56,4.62-7.56c0.05-0.08,0.15-0.12,0.24-0.09c4.49,1.44,8.93,3.51,12.67,6.42
                    C280.02,302.53,282.4,305.02,283.89,307.97z M283.61,292.61v6.31c0,0.39-0.19,0.64-0.34,0.79c-0.26,0.24-0.63,0.36-1.02,0.33
                    c-1.17-0.09-2.44-0.37-3.64-0.79c-1.06-0.37-2.07-0.89-3.02-1.5c-1.62-1.04-3.49-2.05-5.65-2.99l0.5-2.38
                    c0.07-0.31-0.13-0.6-0.44-0.7c-1.28-0.42-1.67-1.57-1.78-2.09c-0.27-1.19,0.05-2.43,0.76-3.03c1.42-1.2,2.76-0.33,2.89-0.25
                    c0.24,0.15,0.43,0.18,0.67,0.05c0.11-0.06,0.19-0.19,0.22-0.29c0.29-0.78,0.7-2.03,1.06-3.08l3.08-0.91
                    c2.69,2.03,5.14,2.88,7.21,3.1c0.49,1.49,1.29,4.12,1.8,6.69c0.02,0.08-0.04,0.15-0.12,0.15h-1.58
                    C283.88,292.01,283.61,292.28,283.61,292.61z"/>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</g>

</svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get the position of a point on a path you need to use `path.getPointAtLength`.

Here is what I've done:

I've moved the avatar in a `<defs>` element so that I can use it latter.
Also I've translated everything in the avatar in the origin of the svg canvas.
The `<use>` elements can get an x and a y attributes in order to be able to position the used element on the svg canvas. In Javascript I'm calculating the x and y for the avatar using the `path.getPointAtLength` method.

In this demo an input type range changes the position of the avatar on the path;

In your code you have a `transform` attribute for the avatar. I'm using this transform for the use element.

Also: for the demo I've changed the value of the `viewBox` attribute of your svg element. You may change it back at what you want.

```js
let pathlength = path.getTotalLength();
let pos = path.getPointAtLength(0);


theUse.setAttributeNS(null,"x", pos.x);
theUse.setAttributeNS(null,"y", pos.y);


theRange.addEventListener("input", ()=>{
  let perc = parseInt(theRange.value);
  let leng = pathlength * perc/100;
  pos = path.getPointAtLength(leng);
  theUse.setAttributeNS(null,"x", pos.x);
  theUse.setAttributeNS(null,"y", pos.y);
})
```

```css
svg{border:1px solid;overflow:visible; width:95vh; display:block; margin:1em auto;}
```

```html
<input type="range" id="theRange" value="0"/>

<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="230 200 400 300" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st5{fill:#43A592;stroke:#8C6239;stroke-width:0.5;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st6{fill:none;stroke:#603813;stroke-width:8;stroke-linecap:square;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st7{fill:none;stroke:#603813;stroke-width:8;stroke-linecap:square;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-dasharray:5.0414,12.0993;}
    .st8{fill:#405813;}
    .st9{fill:#7FBFD6;}
</style>
  <defs>
    <g id="avatar"  transform="translate(-276.22, -290.06)">
    <g>
        <g>
            <circle class="st9" cx="276.22" cy="290.06" r="26.83"/>
            <path class="st8" d="M276.22,317.69c-15.23,0-27.62-12.39-27.62-27.62s12.39-27.62,27.62-27.62s27.62,12.39,27.62,27.62
                S291.45,317.69,276.22,317.69z M276.22,264.04c-14.35,0-26.03,11.68-26.03,26.03s11.68,26.03,26.03,26.03
                s26.03-11.68,26.03-26.03S290.57,264.04,276.22,264.04z"/>
        </g>
        <g>
            <g>
                <path class="st16" d="M264.95,293.51c-0.35-0.11-0.74,0.03-0.93,0.35l-4.62,7.56c-0.35,0.58,0.02,1.33,0.7,1.39
                    c3.16,0.29,11.31,1.43,23.76,5.78c0.44,0.15,0.86-0.3,0.65-0.73C283.15,305.1,278.44,297.84,264.95,293.51z"/>
            </g>
            <g>
                <path class="st16" d="M284.68,279.17c-2.01-6.83-8.8-10.85-15.17-8.97c-0.04,0.01-0.09,0.03-0.13,0.04
                    c-0.06-0.01-0.13-0.01-0.19-0.02c-0.07,0.05-0.13,0.09-0.19,0.14c-6.04,2.09-9.34,8.94-7.39,15.59c0,0-0.76,2.95-2.22,5.82
                    c0,0,6.79-0.4,8.31-7.6c0,0,0.02,0.05,0,0l9.33-2.75c0.01,0.03,0,0,0,0c8.13,6.32,13.75,1.44,13.75,1.44
                    S287.35,280.89,284.68,279.17z"/>
            </g>
            <g>
                <path class="st8" d="M296.91,298.57c-0.04-0.3-0.29-0.52-0.59-0.52h-3.56c-0.33,0-0.6,0.27-0.6,0.6c0,1.34-0.33,1.94-0.6,2.2
                    c-0.18,0.18-0.4,0.27-0.65,0.26c-0.47-0.01-1.14-0.76-1.62-1.83c-1.25-2.77-3.05-3.78-4.49-4.12v-1.83
                    c0-0.07,0.06-0.12,0.12-0.12h1.72c0.09,0,0.19-0.02,0.27-0.06c0.25-0.12,0.37-0.39,0.33-0.64c-0.46-2.69-1.3-5.53-1.85-7.27
                    c3.56-0.05,5.75-1.89,5.78-1.92c0.15-0.13,0.22-0.32,0.2-0.51c-0.02-0.19-0.13-0.36-0.3-0.46c-0.03-0.02-3.07-1.76-5.62-3.38
                    c-0.17-0.11-0.31-0.28-0.37-0.47c-2.19-6.54-8.67-10.46-14.95-9.07l0.35-0.89c0.12-0.31-0.04-0.67-0.36-0.78
                    c-0.31-0.11-0.65,0.07-0.77,0.37l-0.34,0.87c-0.05,0.14-0.23,0.19-0.35,0.1l-0.69-0.52c-0.27-0.2-0.65-0.14-0.85,0.13
                    c-0.19,0.27-0.11,0.64,0.15,0.84l0.74,0.55c-5.7,2.43-8.79,9.05-7.12,15.55c0.05,0.2,0.04,0.4-0.03,0.59
                    c-0.34,0.99-1.18,3.34-2.03,5.27c-0.07,0.15-0.08,0.32-0.02,0.47c0.09,0.24,0.32,0.38,0.56,0.38c0.01,0,0.03,0,0.04,0
                    c0.04,0,2.17-0.17,4.39-1.48c0.22,0.56,0.48,1.26,0.69,2.01c-0.4,0.06-0.78,0.29-1,0.66c0,0,0,0,0,0l-4.62,7.56
                    c-0.28,0.45-0.3,1-0.06,1.47c0.24,0.47,0.69,0.78,1.21,0.83c2.93,0.27,11.11,1.37,23.62,5.75c0.12,0.04,0.25,0.06,0.37,0.06
                    c0.32,0,0.62-0.13,0.84-0.38c0.3-0.34,0.37-0.83,0.17-1.24c-0.72-1.48-2.29-4.05-5.38-6.8c0.84,0.21,1.68,0.35,2.49,0.42
                    c0.07,0.01,0.14,0.01,0.2,0.01c0.64,0,1.26-0.23,1.72-0.66c0.47-0.43,0.72-1.02,0.72-1.67v-2.29c2.23,0.86,2.77,2.18,3.39,3.7
                    c0.38,0.93,0.76,1.89,1.54,2.82c0.8,0.96,1.75,1.43,2.91,1.43c0.27,0,0.56-0.03,0.85-0.08
                    C296.75,303.92,297.15,300.37,296.91,298.57z M285.22,280.22c1.65,1.04,3.43,2.09,4.44,2.68c-1.61,0.93-5.77,2.54-11.3-1.25
                    l5.51-1.62C284.32,279.9,284.81,279.97,285.22,280.22z M272.69,270.34c4.78,0,9.32,3.21,11.14,8.16
                    c0.05,0.15-0.03,0.3-0.18,0.35l-5.99,1.76c-0.1,0.03-0.21-0.03-0.24-0.14c-0.25-1-0.74-2.77-1.58-4.6
                    c-1.2-2.63-2.68-4.48-4.37-5.47C271.89,270.36,272.29,270.34,272.69,270.34z M269.12,271.08c0.15-0.15,0.37-0.21,0.57-0.15
                    c4.12,1.11,6.06,7.7,6.59,9.9c0.02,0.1-0.03,0.2-0.13,0.23l-7.73,2.27c-0.1,0.03-0.2-0.02-0.23-0.12
                    C267.48,281.06,265.68,274.45,269.12,271.08z M266.97,272c-0.94,1.77-1.27,4.06-0.98,6.79c0.22,2.01,0.72,3.77,1.04,4.74
                    c0.03,0.1-0.02,0.21-0.13,0.24l-4.61,1.35c-0.15,0.04-0.3-0.05-0.34-0.2C260.81,279.76,262.91,274.58,266.97,272z
                     M261.95,286.82c0.08-0.24,0.28-0.42,0.52-0.49l4.57-1.34c-1.35,4.32-4.91,5.64-6.67,6.03
                    C261.03,289.4,261.63,287.72,261.95,286.82z M283.89,307.97c-12.54-4.37-20.77-5.48-23.74-5.75c-0.16-0.01-0.23-0.13-0.25-0.17
                    c-0.02-0.05-0.07-0.18,0.01-0.31c0,0,4.62-7.56,4.62-7.56c0.05-0.08,0.15-0.12,0.24-0.09c4.49,1.44,8.93,3.51,12.67,6.42
                    C280.02,302.53,282.4,305.02,283.89,307.97z M283.61,292.61v6.31c0,0.39-0.19,0.64-0.34,0.79c-0.26,0.24-0.63,0.36-1.02,0.33
                    c-1.17-0.09-2.44-0.37-3.64-0.79c-1.06-0.37-2.07-0.89-3.02-1.5c-1.62-1.04-3.49-2.05-5.65-2.99l0.5-2.38
                    c0.07-0.31-0.13-0.6-0.44-0.7c-1.28-0.42-1.67-1.57-1.78-2.09c-0.27-1.19,0.05-2.43,0.76-3.03c1.42-1.2,2.76-0.33,2.89-0.25
                    c0.24,0.15,0.43,0.18,0.67,0.05c0.11-0.06,0.19-0.19,0.22-0.29c0.29-0.78,0.7-2.03,1.06-3.08l3.08-0.91
                    c2.69,2.03,5.14,2.88,7.21,3.1c0.49,1.49,1.29,4.12,1.8,6.69c0.02,0.08-0.04,0.15-0.12,0.15h-1.58
                    C283.88,292.01,283.61,292.28,283.61,292.61z"/>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</g>
  </defs>
<g>
    <path class="st7" id="path" d="M253.83,291.92C438.6,278.28,338.5,457,422.2,429.99c87.72-28.31-71.17-110.68,22.64-190.57
        c54.07-46.05,161.79-22.03,138.18,79.89c-13.69,59.11-53.79,87.21-30.99,132.4c0,0,20.26,23.49,61.35,18.96"/>
</g>

<use id="theUse"  transform="translate(0,20)" xlink:href="#avatar" />
</svg>
```

Comment: that is exactly the thing I could not find. Didn't know where to search for, where to start. Thanks!