# Animating SVG on a curved path in Internet Explorer

Tags: animation, internet-explorer, svg, path, cross-browser

I'm trying to animate along a path based on this post: [move SVG group on path trail based on percentage of whole path trail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54784003/move-svg-group-on-path-trail-based-on-percentage-of-whole-path-trail)

It works beautifully in all browsers but Internet Explorer. I've read lots of posts about the lack of support in IE but I still have enough users that use it that I need to consider it. Can I convert this to another method?

Here is my code (simplified icon here, more complex icon in CodePen):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Jeep Test 5</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #carRight{visibility: visible;}
        #carLeft{visibility: hidden;}
        #carRightIsoBack {visibility: hidden;}
        #carRightIsoFront {visibility: hidden;}
        #carLeftIsoBack {visibility: hidden;}
        #carLeftIsoFront {visibility: hidden;}
    </style>
    <script src="../SiteAssets/js/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="range" id="theRange" value="0"/>
<div id="percentage"></div>
    
    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 459 257" style="enable-background:new 0 0 459 257;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    #percentage{border:1px solid red; padding: 5px;}
svg{border:1px solid;overflow:visible; width:95vh; display:block; margin:1em auto;}
    .st0{fill:none;stroke:#F1EA0D;stroke-width:5;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st1{fill:#1A1A1A;}
    .st2{fill:#FF0000;}

</style>

<defs>
<g id="carRight" transform="translate(-90, -240)">
        <circle class="st3" cx="134.5" cy="215.2" r="12"/>
</g>
</defs>
        <path id="path" class="st0" d="M20.5,249.5c0,0,27,0,54,1s47.36-5,61-13c40.32-23.66,50.1-50.05,3-82c-35.12-23.83-65-19-97-44
    c-22.4-17.5-21.92-28.85-1-41c31-18,101.15-43.54,158-27c55,16,48,30,45,61s-8,39-13,60s5.09,40.12,17,56c18,24,56.49,26.8,81,17
    c10-4,33-17,29-48c-3.36-26.03-15-34-30-53s-4.97-25.67,7-27c18-2,32.57-1.81,59,7c24,8,54,9,65,4s1-22-9-32s-14-17-30-24
    s-34-8-53-3s-28,11-44,14s-26-10-18-25s22-28,42-38c4-2,9-4,9-4"/>
            <use id="theUse_car_right"  transform="translate(0,20)" xlink:href="#carRight" />

    </svg>

<script type="text/javascript">
    let pathlength = path.getTotalLength();
    let pos = path.getPointAtLength(0);

    theUse_car_right.setAttributeNS(null,"x", pos.x);
    theUse_car_right.setAttributeNS(null,"y", pos.y);

    document.getElementById("percentage").textContent = "Completion=0%";

    theRange.addEventListener("input", ()=>{
      let perc = parseInt(theRange.value);
      let leng = pathlength * perc/100;
      pos = path.getPointAtLength(leng);
      theUse_car_right.setAttributeNS(null,"x", pos.x);
      theUse_car_right.setAttributeNS(null,"y", pos.y);

        
    document.getElementById("percentage").textContent = "Completion=" + perc + "%";
       }) 
  
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Demo'd here: https://codepen.io/mrsgorgon/pen/ExNbEPN

Comment: Yu Zhou, that fixed it perfectly! I upvoted it but I'm too new for it to show. Do you recommend any guides on functions that don't work in IE? I am unfortunately required to support it.

Comment: About the functions not working in IE, there's no list. Usually, IE doesn't support ES6 and above syntax. If the function is not supported in IE, the console will show errors. You can use F12 dev tools in IE to check if there's any errors.

Comment: For "theRange", the percentage of the path animated, I need to use a number loaded from a database instead of a number selected on a range form element. The animation would play on page load. I am trying to figure out what I would increase incrementally until the length = theRange. Do I increase perc incrementally until it equals pathlength * perc / 100;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue of your code is in the JavaScript.

1. [Arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#browser_compatibility) `=>` is not supported in IE. You need to use the traditional function expression.
2. The `input` event on input range won't be triggerrd in IE. You need to use `change` event to monitor the change of the input range. But `change` event won't be triggered in other modern browsers, so we need to combine the two event handlers.

   I define the function as `moveit` and combine the two event handlers like this:

   ```
   <input type="range" id="theRange" value="0" oninput="moveit()" onchange="moveit()" />
   ```

The complete sample code is like this:

```js
let pathlength = path.getTotalLength();
let pos = path.getPointAtLength(0);

theUse_car_right.setAttributeNS(null, "x", pos.x);
theUse_car_right.setAttributeNS(null, "y", pos.y);

document.getElementById("percentage").textContent = "Completion=0%";

function moveit() {
  let perc = parseInt(theRange.value);
  let leng = pathlength * perc / 100;
  pos = path.getPointAtLength(leng);
  theUse_car_right.setAttributeNS(null, "x", pos.x);
  theUse_car_right.setAttributeNS(null, "y", pos.y);
  document.getElementById("percentage").textContent = "Completion=" + perc + "%";
}
```

```css
#carRight {
  visibility: visible;
}

#carLeft {
  visibility: hidden;
}

#carRightIsoBack {
  visibility: hidden;
}

#carRightIsoFront {
  visibility: hidden;
}

#carLeftIsoBack {
  visibility: hidden;
}

#carLeftIsoFront {
  visibility: hidden;
}

#percentage {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 5px;
}

svg {
  border: 1px solid;
  overflow: visible;
  width: 95vh;
  display: block;
  margin: 1em auto;
}

.st0 {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #F1EA0D;
  stroke-width: 5;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}

.st1 {
  fill: #1A1A1A;
}

.st2 {
  fill: #FF0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="range" id="theRange" value="0" oninput="moveit()" onchange="moveit()" />
<div id="percentage"></div>
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 459 257" style="enable-background:new 0 0 459 257;" xml:space="preserve">
<defs>
<g id="carRight" transform="translate(-90, -240)">
    <circle class="st3" cx="134.5" cy="215.2" r="12" />
</g>
</defs>
    <path id="path" class="st0" d="M20.5,249.5c0,0,27,0,54,1s47.36-5,61-13c40.32-23.66,50.1-50.05,3-82c-35.12-23.83-65-19-97-44
    c-22.4-17.5-21.92-28.85-1-41c31-18,101.15-43.54,158-27c55,16,48,30,45,61s-8,39-13,60s5.09,40.12,17,56c18,24,56.49,26.8,81,17
    c10-4,33-17,29-48c-3.36-26.03-15-34-30-53s-4.97-25.67,7-27c18-2,32.57-1.81,59,7c24,8,54,9,65,4s1-22-9-32s-14-17-30-24
    s-34-8-53-3s-28,11-44,14s-26-10-18-25s22-28,42-38c4-2,9-4,9-4" />
    <use id="theUse_car_right" transform="translate(0,20)" xlink:href="#carRight" />
    </svg>
```