# Animating SVG on a path when window loads

Tags: animation, internet-explorer, svg, path

I have an SVG that animates along a path when a range slider is moved: [Animating SVG on a curved path in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66340599/animating-svg-on-a-curved-path-in-internet-explorer/66345407#66345407)

However, I'd like the animation to occur when the window loads. Preferably, I'd like it to animate to a percentage of the path (theRange). theRange is a set number which I change in the code (it indicates percentage of people that completed a survey. I'd like to keep some way of tracking the percentage that the avatar has traveled, because I want to trigger popup windows when "perc" reaches 40 and 60. Client requires it to work in IE 10.

Here it is in CodePen: https://codepen.io/mrsgorgon/pen/yLVjaVL

Below is what I have so far. Nothing happens, but I get no errors either.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Avatar Simple Test 2</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        svg{overflow:visible; width:100vh; height: 100vh; display:block; margin:0 auto;}
    </style>
</head>

<body>
        <div id="percentage"></div>
    
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 432 254" style="enable-background:new 0 0 432 254;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:none;stroke:#F1EA0D;stroke-width:5;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st1{fill:#FF0000;}
</style>
<path id="road" class="st0" d="M26.56,231.06c0,0,23.33-0.64,47.31,0.24s41.03-7.21,52.94-14.64c31.62-19.74,37.37-42.74-2.11-71.83
    c-30.34-22.36-57.72-16.87-86.14-39.07C18.67,90.22,19.1,80.13,37.67,69.35C65.2,53.36,127.5,30.69,177.98,45.37
    c48.84,14.21,42.63,26.64,39.96,54.17c-2.66,27.53-7.1,34.63-11.54,53.28s4.52,35.63,15.1,49.73c15.98,21.31,50.16,23.8,71.93,15.1
    c8.88-3.55,29.3-15.1,25.75-42.63c-2.98-23.12-13.32-30.19-26.64-47.07s-4.41-22.8,6.22-23.98c15.98-1.78,28.93-1.61,52.39,6.22
    c21.31,7.1,47.95,7.99,57.72,3.55c9.77-4.44,0.89-19.54-7.99-28.42s-12.43-15.1-26.64-21.31s-30.19-7.1-47.07-2.66
    c-16.87,4.44-24.86,9.77-39.07,12.43s-23.09-8.88-15.98-22.2c7.1-13.32,19.54-24.86,37.3-33.75c3.55-1.78,3.16-1.2,3.16-1.2"/>
<defs>
    <circle id="avatar" class="st1" cx="27.5" cy="230.5" r="14"/>
</defs>
        <use id="theUse_avatar"  transform="translate(-30,-230)" xlink:href="#avatar" />
</svg>

<script type="text/javascript">
    let roadlength = road.getTotalLength();
    let pos = road.getPointAtLength(0);
    let theRange = 70;

    theUse_avatar.setAttributeNS(null,"x", pos.x);
    theUse_avatar.setAttributeNS(null,"y", pos.y);
    
    function moveit() {
        let perc = parseInt(theRange.value);
        let leng = 1;
        while (leng < roadlength * perc / 100) {
            theUse_avatar.setAttributeNS(null, "x", pos.x);
            theUse_avatar.setAttributeNS(null, "y", pos.y);
            document.getElementById("percentage").textContent = "Completion=" + perc + "%";
            leng++;
        }
    }
        window.onload = moveit;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to modify your above-mentioned code sample as per your said requirements.

Modified code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Avatar Simple Test 2</title>
      <style type="text/css">
         svg{overflow:visible; width:100vh; height: 100vh; display:block; margin:0 auto;}
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="percentage"></div>
      <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
         viewBox="0 0 432 254" style="enable-background:new 0 0 432 254;" xml:space="preserve">
         <style type="text/css">
            .st0{fill:none;stroke:#F1EA0D;stroke-width:5;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
            .st1{fill:#FF0000;}
         </style>
         <path id="road" class="st0" d="M26.56,231.06c0,0,23.33-0.64,47.31,0.24s41.03-7.21,52.94-14.64c31.62-19.74,37.37-42.74-2.11-71.83
            c-30.34-22.36-57.72-16.87-86.14-39.07C18.67,90.22,19.1,80.13,37.67,69.35C65.2,53.36,127.5,30.69,177.98,45.37
            c48.84,14.21,42.63,26.64,39.96,54.17c-2.66,27.53-7.1,34.63-11.54,53.28s4.52,35.63,15.1,49.73c15.98,21.31,50.16,23.8,71.93,15.1
            c8.88-3.55,29.3-15.1,25.75-42.63c-2.98-23.12-13.32-30.19-26.64-47.07s-4.41-22.8,6.22-23.98c15.98-1.78,28.93-1.61,52.39,6.22
            c21.31,7.1,47.95,7.99,57.72,3.55c9.77-4.44,0.89-19.54-7.99-28.42s-12.43-15.1-26.64-21.31s-30.19-7.1-47.07-2.66
            c-16.87,4.44-24.86,9.77-39.07,12.43s-23.09-8.88-15.98-22.2c7.1-13.32,19.54-24.86,37.3-33.75c3.55-1.78,3.16-1.2,3.16-1.2"/>
         <defs>
            <circle id="avatar" class="st1" cx="27.5" cy="230.5" r="14"/>
         </defs>
         <use id="theUse_avatar"  transform="translate(-30,-230)" xlink:href="#avatar" />
      </svg>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         var roadlength = parseInt(road.getTotalLength());
         var pos = road.getPointAtLength(0);
         var theRange = 70;
         theUse_avatar.setAttributeNS(null, "x", pos.x);
         theUse_avatar.setAttributeNS(null, "y", pos.y);
         function moveit() 
         {
         
         var i;
         for (i = 1; i <=theRange; i++) 
         {  
         var perc = i;
         var myval= roadlength * perc / 100;
         var path= road.value;
         pos1 = road.getPointAtLength(myval);       
         task(i, myval, pos1); 
         
             }
         }
         function task(i,myval, pos1) 
         { 
         setTimeout(function() 
         { 
            theUse_avatar.setAttributeNS(null, "x", pos1.x);
            theUse_avatar.setAttributeNS(null, "y", pos1.y);
            document.getElementById("percentage").textContent = "Completion=" + i + "%";
         },  100 * i); 
         }
             window.onload = moveit();
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

**Output in the IE 11(document mode: IE 10):**

[image]

Further, you can try to modify the code sample as per your own requirements.

Comment: Perfect! I knew I needed a loop but obviously didn't know how to write it. This works in IE!